# Can we put the soup / water (or other liquids) on the table?

Tags: usage

Can we put the soup / water (and other liquids) on the table while they are in vessels that hold them?

For example, if my friend brings me a plate with soup, or water bottle, could I tell him "put the soup or the water on the table please" even he doesn't really put **directly** the soup or the water on the table but he puts there **a plate with** soup or the **bottle of** water?

Comment: This question is very confusing (at least to me). You should probably edit it and explain your question a little bit better. I'm having a hard time telling what "both things" refers to: soup and water? Especially since the first one is a question, and the second one is a recommendation.

Comment: Thank you. I edited it. Is it better understood now?

Comment: Yes. Why would you think you can't say this? Do you know a language in which it can't be said?

Comment: Because I was in a situation today in which I was told by a non native English speaker that it's not acurate to say it in any language.  He caused me to ponder about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: **Yes.**

**In table parlance:**

**You can put the soup on the table.**
**You can put the water on the table.**

In the case of soup, it will be in a tureen and served into plates at the table.
**Or:** It can mean put the individuals bowls of soup on the table, which have already been served.

The same goes for water except: the water would be in a glass or ceramic jug.

If the water is to be drunk from glasses, you would say:
 Put the water glasses on the table.

If glasses of water are ready to be put on the table, you can say: 
Please put the water on the table.

The water could mean: the jug of water or the individual glasses of water that are already poured.

Some people may use water bottles on tables, I don't.

Comment: When we put the meat on the table, we generally interpose a plate or dish, to stop the meat juices staining the tablecloth.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Who said anything about meat? After that nasty comment  you made to me on the other site, I can only think you are at it again. This is about soup and water.